# Capture Facebook's JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

I am having a registration form that prefills data from facebook profile. When I click on register, I want it to be redirect to a page which displays the details entered in the registration form. 
I am using the below code which will redirect me to the page where I want to display information:

```
<fb:registration redirect-uri="page-displaying-the-json-data"
 fields="name,gender,birthday,email"></fb:registration>
```

My JSON response will look something like this:

```
{
   "oauth_token": "...big long string...",
   "expires": 1291840400,
   "issued_at": 1291836800,
   "name": "..."
   "gender": "male",
   "birthday": "12/16/1985",
   "email": abc@xyz.com
 }
```

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to show? It's not clear!

Comment: I want to show the fields: name, email, birthday from the json response.